# Anchoring a sprite to a specific x & y on another, regardless of rotation [Gamemaker]

Tags: coordinates, game-maker

I have a sprite, `sDetritus`, with a corresponding object, `oDetritus`, and an `sTurret` and `oTurret`.

If I apply no rotation (i.e. changing the image_angle) to `oDetritus`, I can anchor the `oTurret` to a specific position on the ODetritus, using its sprite as a guideline. In this case, the desired x and y for the `oTurret`, in relation to the `oDetritus`'s x and y origin, are *x - 37* and *y + 192*.

I can make the `oDetritus` the `Owner` of the `oTurret`, and make sure that the `oTurret` 'sticks' with the following in its Step event:

```
if instance_exists(Owner) {
x = Owner.x - 37
y = Owner.y + 192
}
```

However, how would I adjust this to account for rotating the image_angle of the `oDetritus` object underneath? Obviously then the x and y values would be wrong. I have tried using `lengthdir_x` and `lengthdir_y`, but this doesn't seem to be the correct function here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is classic rotation of a vector. You have your offset vector (-37, 192) which you need to rotate.

```
xoffset = -37;
yoffset = 192;

rotatedxoffset = xoffset * cos(angle) - yoffset * sin(angle);
rotatedyoffset = xoffset * sin(angle) + yoffset * cos(angle);

x = Owner.x + rotatedxoffset;
y = Owner.y + rotatedyoffset;
```

If you are interested in learning why this is the case, you can learn about matrices and 2d transformations.

Comment: Thanks! It's about time I actually learnt about cos and sin :)